Parge old brick before waterproofing and insulating?
I have a section of my house foundation wall that’s brick. It’s 4’ high and is badly deteriorated from freeze / thaw cycles.
I want to insulate my foundation wall, but I’d like to stabilize / waterproof the brick first.  If I parge it, I can waterproof it more easily, but I’m not sure of the best approach.  I’m considering a wire mesh anchored to the brick for the initial layer, then building up before I apply the water proofing.
But what do I use for parging? Masonry cement?  Mortar mix?
Do I use a binder? I’ve heard of some who used Elmer’s glue directly in the mix, which makes a degree of sense.
Regardless, perhaps I should parge by attaching cement board to 1x3 cleats anchored to the brick instead so i can waterproof a surface that isn’t going to deteriorate.
Really have no idea the best course here.

See: https://www.rhinoshieldin.com/can-rhino-shield-go-on-brick  for an interesting alternative. (I have no connection with this company.)

This degrading of masonry only happens out the outside of the foundation, is this where this is occuring? Or is it inside the building? If it is the outside, where is the floor level in respect to this picture?

The still beam sits on top of the brick wall here. This is the top 4’ of the foundation wall, the remainder is stacked stone.  This is a protected area under a side porch, so it isn’t directly exposed to the elements, but yes, the bricks have spalled from a lack of parge and freeze/thaw cycles.
